# How do I use X-Values in MPAndroid Charts?

Tags: android, charts, visualization, mpandroidchart

I have been using MPAndroid Charts for while now. Today after adding grandle dependency for the library, few things had been changed.

```
 float YValues [] = {50, 30, 0, 60, 70};
 String [] xValues = {"Fifty", "Thirty", "Zero", "Sixty", "Seventy"};

 ArrayList<BarEntry> yData = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < YValues.length; i ++)
            yData.add(new BarEntry(YValues[i], i));

        ArrayList<String> xData = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < xValues.length; i ++)
            xData.add(xValues[i]);

        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yData, "");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.invalidate();
```

My Question is where do I put `xData` variable. Initially I used to say 
`BarData barData = new BarData(xData, barDataSet);` but this is not working. Where do I put xData variable or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the earlier versions of this library, this constructor was definitely present. But it's not there in the [current version](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/d7e659a1fac34f1d187d2ac259a415302ba2cadf/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/BarData.java) of BarData class. As sad as it may sound, you can go back to an earlier version by changing your gradle dependencies and use that constructor that we all are familiar with.

There are several BarChart [examples](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample) present that use the newer version, however either they don't have an X-axis at all or if they do, they all have integer values set using `BarEntry` and formatted using a custom value formatter. Its also possible that I am missing something entirely.

Comment: Thanks and thanks again. At least you understood my problem. I have changed grandle to reflect earlier versions and it worked but still am afraid in case I need this library in future.. Something might go mess.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure how you're implementing your code, but for adding entry to the data set should be like this.

```
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(50f,0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(30f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(60f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(70f, 4));

    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "");

    // creating labels
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("fifty");
    labels.add("thirty");
    labels.add("zero");
    labels.add("sixty");
    labels.add("seventy");

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
```

Try this if its settles what you're looking for then congratulations, if not. Maybe you could explain better.

Comment: Have your tried to use the latest library? `BarData data = new BarData(lables, dataset)` is not working. Meaning the `BarData` constructor string has been removed as the first parameter. However, this one is working `BarData bardata = new BarData(datasetObj)` is working nice, Same case for the `PieData` and the rest..... Okay you are doing it right, but for the latest release the thing is not working

Comment: I think I have explained better and now you can get it round and clear. I have been using MPAndroid Charts for a while, but now I can't use them till I figureout how to solve this

Comment: you did not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

In new MpAndroidChart BarData constructor is changed.If you need to add labels to xAxis use the following code.

```
//xAxis labels
final ArrayList<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    xLabel.add("day 1");
    xLabel.add("day 2");
    xLabel.add("day 3");
    xLabel.add("day 4");
    xLabel.add("day 5"); 


//Get xAxis from the barchart
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
```